# What is the best way to ask a string prompt into a number?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, numbers, var

What I was able to find while looking through stackoverflow was that this is the best way to prompt a string and turn it into a number. Is this the best way? Thank you!

```js
var age = prompt("Please enter your age:");
if (Number(age) < 18) {
  alert("");
}
```

Comment: There are many ways, but your way is fine.

Comment: "Best" is a tricky thing to ask for. It will lead to opinionated answers. For example, I think `+x` (which was answered below) is a bad way of converting to a number because it is not explicit, I prefer `Number(x)`. Someone else will probably explain why they think `parseInt` is better, and so on.

Comment: what @Barmar said... you could also use parseInt(). either way check for NaN afterward

Comment: Thanks for proving my point. 

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

Prepend a `+` to it.  That's the simplest way.

For example:

```js
+'123.456'
```